# Can you mirror the Apple Watch during a demo

Tags: apple-watch

Is there a way to mirror what's on the Apple Watch to another screen?  This would be for a internal demo purpose.  Or suggestions on how to demo an app to a large (more than one person) group?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do what you describe. Your best bet currently is to run your app in the simulator or point a camera at your Watch.