# Trying to mirror Apple Watch screen for demo

Tags: ios, xcode, screen-capture, mirror, watchos-2

it seems like that the only way to mirror an Apple Watch app is to use the simulator and display this on the screen or pointing a camera to it, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30223424/can-you-mirror-the-apple-watch-during-a-demo).

As the Q/A dates to May 2015 I was wondering if there are any updates/news on this.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no updates to this situation yet, as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I've used CamTwist to solve this. Select'Desktop+' as video source in PIP mode. Configure the Desktop+ source  to use the Watch simulator screen as input, cropping the menu bar. Than add a Slide Show source with some nice picture of an Apple Watch. In the PIP settings, scale, move and crop the simulator video-feed until it overlays the watch face of the slide-show picture. Via the CamTwist tools menu, set the resulting video-feed full screen on any connected monitor or projector.

The Watch Simulator itself stays on the primary screen and can be controlled via mouse/keyboard. Even when the simulator is minimised or hidden, CamTwist continuous to show the 'live picture'.

See http://camtwiststudio.com (I've used v2.4 on OSX 10.10.4, not tested with 2.5 or higher..)

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Why you don't use AirPlay? It's build-in support of Watch, I use it for my client demo in SEA (South East Asia).

Comment: Please provide some more details. As far as I know it's not possible (yet) to mirror the Apple Watch screen using AirPlay.

Comment: update to watch OS 2.0, open Glance, move to first glance, you gonna see it.

Comment: Do you have any resource to show me an example? I can't find anything about AirPlay mirroring on the Apple Watch.

Comment: Phong Nguyen, I couldn't find any resource saying that AirPlay on the Watch does anything more then streaming music. I've not seen it stream it's screen as well. So if you know how, please let us know.